# Python (Selenium) Selecting a drop down list from HHPRED

Tags: python, selenium, biopython

I'm attempting to select drop down menu items from the HHPRED website. (URL: https://toolkit.tuebingen.mpg.de/tools/hhpred) and I keep bumping into either 'object not found,' or 'object not clickable/selectable'.

```
# Input protein from txt file (predator_file variable)
text_area = driver.find_element_by_id('__BVID__121')
text_area.send_keys(predator_file)

# Input PDB, SCOP, PFAM, and NCBI domains

 first_click = driver.find_element_by_id('__BVID__130')
 scop_click = driver.find_element_by_link_text("SCOPe")
 pfam_click = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Pfam")
 ncbi_click = driver.find_element_by_link_text("ncbi_")
```

I know I'm working on selenium correctly because the first portion for my text entry is copying correctly but, when I'm working on the drop down from selecting it to even picking what I need - I'm lost. See below the inspected elements for HHPRED and the drop down I'm looking at tackling.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your url is unreachable due tooc credntials. You can use below code to select value/visible text from the dropdown.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select 

select= WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "select element xpath")))

print(len(select.options))
select.select_by_value("")          # select by value
select.select_by_visible_text('')  # select by visible text
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='element_name']/option[text()='option_text']").click()
```

**Updated solution** : its a custom dropdown element so you need to handle it in a differnt way . Kindly find below code for your reference. I have verified it and its working as expected .

```
driver.get("https://toolkit.tuebingen.mpg.de/tools/hhpred")
main_window = driver.current_window_handle
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn sign-in-link btn-href btn-sm']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//fieldset[@class='form-group']//input)[2]"))).send_keys('')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//fieldset[@class='form-group']//input)[3]"))).send_keys('')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-secondary']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Got it!')]"))).click()

print wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Paste Example')]"))).text
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
clickElement=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='multiselect__tags']")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(clickElement).click().perform()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[*]//span[contains(text(),'TIGRFAMs_v15.0')]"))).click()
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: The URL is public domain and does not require a login. I recognized that I put in the wrong URL. 

https://toolkit.tuebingen.mpg.de/tools/hhpred


I will try to use this code and get back to you as soon as I can. 

Thank you, 

~BD

Comment: I've tried running the code with the Xpath along with the above code and I am still running into errors. "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:"

I'm already using time, I support to rephrase, how do I locate the correct path to look?

Comment: I cant replicate this issue locally as i dont have credentials to login. is it possible for you to provide me credentials to login